# Listbox not displaying data even though items are definitely being added

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listbox

I'm currently implementing a server/client system were the client registers with a server by clicking on it in a list box and then the server responds with a list of feeds. The only issue is my listbox is not updating with the feeds.

I've debugged the entire process and I can say that the data is definitely reaching the method that populates the listbox but for some reason it's like it's not refreshing. I've tried calling:

```
lstAvailableFeeds.DataSource = null;
lstAvailableFeeds.DataSource = testSource;
```

and

```
lstAvailableFeeds.Hide();
lstAvailableFeeds.Show();
```

As my listbox runs on the UI thread and the feed retrieval on a separate thread I invoke the listbox as you would expect and my data makes it to the following method but nothing happens visually.

```
public void RefreshAvailableFeeds(List<FeedsMessage> receivedFeeds)
{
    foreach (FeedsMessage feed in receivedFeeds)
    {
        lstAvailableFeeds.Items.Add("testing");
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Number of items in list" + lstAvailableFeeds.Items.Count);
}
```

Any ideas/suggestions would be much appreciated!

(PS tried to upload an image of intellisense showing that the items where in the listbox (lstAvailableFeeds) but my low reputation rating wouldn't allow)

Comment: You need to call a DataBind() method where are you binding the data
also is this a windows app or console app.. why not use a message Dialog to display the items using the List Items along with a `Join` extension method call..? this is incorrect `lstAvailableFeeds.Show();` call the `form.Show()`

Comment: Add `this.Show();` so you can see the form.  Yup, wrong form object reference.

Comment: DJKraze - it is a windows form applciation, i'm just writing to the output window for debug purposes. 

Hans Passant - the actual form is showing already, the listbox just displays nothing.

Comment: DJKraze - i tried hiding the form and reshowing with no luck.

Hans - Is it possible that the invoke is on the wrong object?

Comment: To rephrase, when I call invoke I set the form as a static method upon running and then call this in the feed retrieval thread Program.rssClient.InvokeStoriesListbox(lstStories);

I know that this is not the way it should be done, but it has worked in the past.

Comment: I've fixed it! Massive thanks to Hans! It turned out i had mistakenly created two object references to the same form :(